# Ansible: Get Variable with inventory_hostname

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

I have the following passwords file `vault.yml`:

```yaml
---
server1: "pass1"
server2: "pass2"
server3: "pass3"
```

I am loading these values in a variable called `passwords`:

```yaml
- name: Get Secrets
  set_fact:
    passwords: "{{ lookup('template', './vault.yml')|from_yaml }}"
  delegate_to: localhost
- name: debug it
  debug:
    var: passwords.{{ inventory_hostname }}
```

The result of the debugging task shows me the result I want to get: The password for the specific host.

But if I set the following in a variables file:

```yaml
---
ansible_user: root
ansible_password: passwords.{{ inventory_hostname }}
```

This will not give me the desired result. The `ansible_password` takes "passwords" literally and not as a variable.

How can I achieve the same result I got when debugging the `passwords.{{ inventory_hostname }}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the part

> ... if I set the following in a variables file ...

I am not sure since I miss some information about your use case and data flow. However, in general the syntax `ansible_password: "{{ PASSWORDS[inventory_hostname] }}"` might work for you.

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    PASSWORDS:
      SERVER1: "pass1"
      SERVER2: "pass2"
      SERVER3: "pass3"
      localhost: "pass_local"

  tasks:

  - name: Debug var
    debug:
      var: PASSWORDS

  - name: Set Fact 'ansible_password'
    set_fact:
      ansible_password: "{{ PASSWORDS[inventory_hostname] }}"

  - name: Debug var
    debug:
      var: ansible_password
```

In that way you can access a element by name.